# Not working index method in Asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-8

After long fight to publish my asp.net core app to webserver I finally did it and now everything working beside index method from admin controller which is specified as default.

```
 public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Admin Panel";

        var model = new AdminViewModel()
        {
            Paging = new PaginationSettings()
            {
                ItemsPerPage = 4,
                CurrentPage = page,
                ShowFirstLast = true,
                TotalItems = _newsData.GetAll().Count()
            },
            Category = _newsData.GetAllCats()

        };
        model.Newses = _newsData.Pagination(page);


        return View(model);
    }
```

Browser only throwing 500 error and saying that the website is not working.
If anybody know what to do pleas reply.
//Edit: 
This is error from logfile:

> warn: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[59]
>         Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
>   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
>         Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Post the error message from the log file. Without it, its hard to help you

Comment: Is your view in the publish folder?

Comment: If you put the "Index" at url, works?

Comment: @RafaelRibeiro no it doesn't,
 the View folder is in publish project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in IIS, and it occurs when an application using `DataProtection` is hosted in the Kestrel/IIS combination. It's putting your ephemeral keys into memory instead of the machine registry, which means they all get disposed when the app pool stops.

There is more discussion about this bug [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/102). The problem seems to be solved by [running this PowerShell script](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/dev/Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1) on the server. You can read a bit more about the script [in this GitHub thread](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/pull/106).

Comment: not really sure but it started work after I added data protection service:
'code' services.AddDataProtection()
               .ProtectKeysWithDpapi(true)
               .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@".\Source\")); 
I am not sure becuase it took a while. Meanwhile I was contacting to server helpdesk but they couldn't do anything.